# How to create an y axis containing hours from noon to noon on the next day

Tags: d3.js

I will appreciate if someone can help with a chart I need to build. Its vertical (y) axis must contain the hours from noon to the noon on the next day. Basically it should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';

...
const startOfDay = new Date();
startOfDay.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0);

const middleOfNextDay = addDays(new Date(), 1);
middleOfNextDay.setHours(14, 0, 0, 0);

const yScale = scaleTime()
  .domain([startOfDay, middleOfNextDay])
  .rangeRound([0, height]);

g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(timeFormat('%H:%M')).ticks(timeHour, 2));
```